# After changing php version to php 7 nginx error bad gateway

Tags: apache, nginx

Our website is working on php 5.6 version, but after switching to php 7, there occures 502 error. Could anyone tell me how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

[Here's my log.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT1gI.png)

Comment: I'm a little confused here because your question says "nginx" but these are apache logs... can we see your nginx config file ?

Comment: All the errors are written to apache logs, timeweb hosting support says that nginx logs are not available for watching.

Comment: finally the hoster did it himself